# Real Analysis - Notation

Tags: real-analysis, notation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHU55.png)

Hi I am studying Real Analysis and sometime i see a _ on top of a function or a set and i don't understand what does it mean or it doesn't mean anything and it is just an arbitrary symbol.

Thanks you

Comment: The first bar on top of the set is the closure, or set of adherent points of $A$, as written in the bottom. However, closure is taken with respect to a norm (or metric or topology) which is pointed out to be uniform convergence in the next paragraph. The contextual definition is the "that is" part after that. The other bar is on top of a function, which is it's conjugate. The definition is on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

1. is $M $ a subset of a metric space, then $\overline{M}$ denotes the closure of $M$.
2. for a complex number $z$, $\overline{z}$ denotes the conjugate complex number.